# SUM minutes SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, time, sum

HI guys,
My litle problem goes like this :
I have this columns : PHONE_NR , TIME ( time field ), Meaning the calling telephone number and call duration. I need to group phone nr and sum the minutes. Filds looks like this :

```
 nr          time 
726028xxx 00:07:07 
735560css 00:07:37 
726028xxx 00:07:55
```

Comment: if your question was solved, you should mark an answer as accepted.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT PHONE_NR, SUM(DATEPART(minute, TIME)) FROM [table] GROUP BY PHONE_NR;
```

As far as I know this should work for both SQL Server `DATETIME` and the 2008 `TIME` data-types.

Example:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE
(
    phone_nr varchar(10),
    call_time TIME
);

INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES ('726028xxx', '00:07:07');
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES ('735560css', '00:07:37');
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES ('726028xxx', '00:07:55');

SELECT phone_nr, SUM(DATEPART(minute, call_time)) AS total_call_time FROM @tbl GROUP BY phone_nr;
```

Results in:

```
phone_nr  | minutes
726028xxx | 14
735560css | 7
```

**EDIT**:

This version is identical to the above, except it also takes into account the seconds and hours (e.g. 1hr 7min 07secs = 67.117 minutes) so it's much more accurate.

```
SELECT 
    phone_nr, 
    SUM(CAST(DATEPART(second, call_time) + (DATEPART(minute, call_time) * 60) + (DATEPART(hour, call_time) * 3600) AS decimal) / 60) AS total_call_time
FROM 
    @tbl
GROUP BY
    phone_nr;
```

Results in the following if the first record was `01:07:07`.

```
phone_nr  | minutes
726028xxx | 75.033332
735560css | 7.616666
```

Comment: Will this continue to work if a call lasts more than an hour?

Comment: @Robin - it would need editing to include the hour component as well - I had just edited this into my answer!

Comment: @Robin, I've just edited my answer again so it works for hours as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use DATEDIFF to get the total number of minutes that have passed since time "zero"

```
SELECT
 [PHONE_NR],
 SUM(DATEDIFF(minute, '00:00:00', [TIME]))
FROM
 [YourTable]
GROUP BY
 [PHONE_NR]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @v1 varchar(50)
declare @v2 varchar(50)
set @v1='03:10'
set @v2='01:50'

--select cast(left(v1,2) as int) + cast(left(v2,2)as int)

select 
cast(
cast(left(@v1,2) as int) + cast(left(@v2,2)as int)
+(cast(right(@v1,2) as int) + cast(right(@v2,2) as int))/60 as varchar)

+':'+cast(( cast(right(@v1,2) as int) + cast(right(@v2,2) as int))%60 as varchar)
```